# Prevent button to trigger when it's behind a view with UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I have the following setup :

[image]

1. Blue background at zPosition = 0
2. Yellow button at zPosition = 0 with an action to print "Button tapped"
3. UIView with grey background and 0.8 alpha at zPosition = 1 with a UITapGestureRecognizer with an action to print "Grey view tapped"

When I tapped at the grey area, "Grey view tapped" is printed.
But if I tapped at the location of the yellow button, "Button tapped" is printed.
I expected to always have printed "Grey view tapped" because that view is in front of the button.
How can I prevent the button that is behind a view to be triggered ?

I know that I can set the button to .isEnabled = false but that is not a suitable solution since the grey background is created in a parent view controller from witch all my views are inheriting.

I set the grey view to `.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` (even if it's the default value) as stated here : [In Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41177935/preventing-touches-from-happening-behind-a-view%20but%20the%20button%20is%20still%20being%20triggered.)

I thought using [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/coordinating_multiple_gesture_recognizers/preferring_one_gesture_over_another) but the problem is that there are a button and a gesture recognizer instead of multiple gesture recognizers.

Any idea on how to do this properly?

Comment: I don't think so your button is behind the view. Debug View Hierarchy.

Comment: Will your grey area is always above the button? If not, maybe depending upon the z-position of the view, you can enable and disable the button so that you get the expected feature?

Comment: Thank you @Daljeet, I was able to find the solution. I posted it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Daljeet lead me to the solution. Using the Debug View Hierarchy I realised that my button was on top of the the view. My mistake was because I didn't realised the difference between UIView.layer.zPosition and the order of subviews in the hierarchy. A view can be drawn behind another view but nonetheless be in front in the View Hierarchy.

The solution was to use `view.bringSubviewToFront(greyView)`

Be aware that if you add the button after calling that last line of code, the button will be placed on top of the View Hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

you can use this method to check if the touch was on the button and then trigger your action.

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
if let firstTouch = touches.first {
    let hitView = self.view.hitTest(firstTouch.location(in: yourBtn), with: event)

    if hitView === yourBtn {
        print("touch is inside")
    } else {
        print("touch is outside")
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: I tried that chunk of code and added a print statement only to realise that it was never called